# Is there a way to add this column and it's name that doesn't require significant rewrite?

Tags: r, dataframe

this is a facsimile of the code I have at the moment

```
state_abbr1<- rnorm(8,5,2)
county_code1<- rnorm(8,5,2)
county_name1<- rnorm(8,5,2)

Patient_ID <-c("13962830","20111947", "58786237", "57991640", "79365970", "84356256", "81640916", "71119659")
Sex        <-c( "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male","Female", "Female", "Female", "Female")
Code_test1 <-cbind.data.frame(Patient_ID, Sex)

Clean_Code1<-cbind.data.frame(state_abbr1,county_name1,county_code1)
Clean_Code1[4:32]<-NA
Clean_Code1[,5] <- as.numeric(Code_test1[,"Patient_ID" ])
Clean_Code1[,7] <- as.factor(Code_test1[,"Sex"])
```

etc

Clean_Code and Code_test are both 200000 rows. and Code_test is 32 uniquely named variables, each gets added to Clean_Code in the same fashion in different positions.

I could add some code to each line using the multi cursor but I'd like to avoid having to individually alter all 28 variable inputs. Ideally there's something that will allow me to alter and add the character variables from code_test to Clean_Code while also taking the respective var names from Code_test and applying them to Clean_Code.

Thanks in advance.
p.s. also open to different methods since I will probably have to write code for similar tasks for my next 2 datasets...

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example? and what is the expected output?

Comment: edited for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a vector with column index that you want to replace in `Clean_Code`. Note that you can use `:` to create sequence of index if they are consecutive, if they are not add them manually. Create a similar vector for `Code_test`. For `Code_test` you can create a vector of column index or column names whichever is easy. Both of them should work.

```
clean_code_index <- c(5, 7, 8:12, 15, ....)
code_test_index <- c(1:3, 6,9, .....)
code_test_names <- c("Patient ID", "Sex", .....)
```

You can then copy the values directly.

```
#with index
Clean_Code[clean_code_index] <- Code_test[code_test_index]
#Or with names
Clean_Code[clean_code_index] <- Code_test[code_test_names]
```

Use any one of them from above to copy values.

To copy the names you can either use `code_test_names` or `code_test_index` depending on what you have created.

```
#With names
names(Clean_Code)[clean_code_index] <- code_test_names
#Or with index
names(Clean_Code)[clean_code_index] <- names(Code_test)[code_test_index]
```

Comment: If I understand what you did it shouldn't matter but I edited my post to provide a facsimile of the data I'm working with.

Comment: Did you try my answer? Did it gave you any error? Can you also update your post with the expected output so that I can compare my answer with that?

Comment: I ended up using half your answer. Mostly because I wasn't sure how to apply the indexes in my specific case

Comment: I'm doing another attempt in a different situation using your technique and I wanted to ask your input since it's not quite working, but I'm not sure what the best way to show you my code...

Comment: The best way would be to ask a new question so that you can get help easily and faster.